# Error 404 on static ressources whith parameters on get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, static, routes

I'm doing a biomedical website with node.js and I encounter a problem:
In my app.js (server file), I have these code

```
app.get('/disease/:orphanetID', function(req, res) {
var orphanetID=req.params.orphanetID;
res.render('pages/disease.ejs', {activetitle: "views"});
});
```

The problem is that all static ressources needed in disease.ejs get an error 404.

For example for this code in disease.ejs:

```
<script src="static/js/DOMscripts.js"></script>
```

In chrome console, I see:

```
(red cross) GET http://localhost:8080/disease/static/js/DOMscripts.js
```

The thing is, my static ressource is at http://localhost:8080/static/js/DOMscripts.js, there's just the string "disease" in the URL which appeared... It's not the good URL!

And after testing some stuff, I figured out that this code was working:

```
app.get('/disease', function(req, res) {
//var orphanetID=req.params.orphanetID;
res.render('pages/disease.ejs', {activetitle: "views"});
});
```

So if I don't have any parameter, it's working, but I need it.

For info, my code for for static ressources is:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

What should I do to have a parameter?

Comment: Using page relative URLs for static resources is often a problem because it tells the browser to add the path of the page URL to the static resource URL before requesting it from your server and that is rarely what you want.  Set up your static resources so they all start with a `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script path:

```
<script src="/static/js/DOMscripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain a lot more what's happening here, when you don't start your static resource URLs with a `/` or `//adomain.com/` or `http://adomain.com/`, then the browser makes those URLs relative to the URL of the page.

So, if the page URL is:

```
http://adomain.com/disease/194
```

and you have a resource in the page that is specified as:

```
static/js/DOMscripts.js
```

then the browser will request an URL from the server by combining the path of the page with the relative URL of the resource so you'd get a request for:

```
http://adomain.com/disease/static/js/DOMscripts.js
```

But, your server isn't expecting that.  Your server is expecting:

```
http://adomain.com/static/js/DOMscripts.js
```

So, to fix that you make your URL start with a `/`.  That makes it relative ONLY to the domain of the page, not the path of the page and the browser will request the URL for the resource that you expected.