# What happen when we use express.static("public")?

Tags: javascript, css, express, nodemon

I was running one project on my local server but for using CSS for the same purpose.

Then I get to know for doing the I need to make a folder and use this
code:
`app.use(express.static("public));`

What happens when we use this code and this starts working but normal CSS is not working?

Comment: First off, it would be `app.use(express.static("public"));` (you were missing a close quote).  Second, questions like this can only be answered when you show us exactly  what request is not working.  Show us the HTML that lists the CSS file and show us where the matching CSS file is relative to the public directory is in your file system.

Comment: The most likely cause (which a guess because you haven't supplied the above information) is explained in these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563270/getting-static-files-in-express-js/62564199#62564199 and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361080/error-404-on-static-ressources-whith-parameters-on-get-request/45362477#45362477.